# What causes this strange flashing in my jQuery .fadeTo() effect?

Tags: jquery, fadeto

Here's a page with some thumbnails:

http://thenozzle.net/games

What I want is when you hove over one thumbnail, the others fade to black (there's a black div behind each thumb). Hover off, and they come back.

The issue is when you go from one thumbnail to the next, all the other thumbnails on the page fade in and then out very quickly. How can I prevent this? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('.child-thumb').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
        $('.inactive').children('img').stop(1,1).fadeTo('fast', .3);
            $('.inactive').children('p').stop(1,1).fadeTo('fast', .3);
    },
    function () {
        $('.inactive').children('img').stop(1,1).fadeTo('fast', 1);
            $('.inactive').children('p').stop(1,1).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    }
);
```

NOTE 2: Also, if there's any way I can simplify or compress my code to make it more semantic/faster/lighter, please, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: `.stop()` takes boolean parameters, not 1 or 0.  While you may get away with it here because of automatic type conversion, the proper use of stop is to pass it true/false, not 1/0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using .stop() improperly. The only parameter you could need here is [clearqueue] = true (and that's only if you're worried about your users making two switches in under .3s)

just set all your stops to `.stop(true)`

eg:

```
$('.inactive').children('img').stop(true).fadeTo('fast', .3);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfayG/8/)